# Finding elements using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find and then fill in the username and password of Instagrams login page using:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
from selenium import webdriver
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = filename)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("blankspace")
password.send_keys("blankspace")
```

however, I keep getting an error that it cant detect the element even though the name is correct

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"}
```

The HTML:

```
<input aria-label="Phone number, username, or email" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="75" name="username" type="text" class="_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP" value="">
```

Comment: @Joel This question does not refer to getting the source at all.

Comment: Try to debug the HTML source the driver sees [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=source#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source). It is highly probable that Instagram detects you aren't human and is asking you some captcha before you can view the page. Because your code is sound, otherwise.

Comment: @edd you seem to be right, its not asking for a captcha but the page loads most of the elements after you get to the page so I added a `time.sleep(5)` and then tried to find the elements and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the cookie consent popup first before accessing the form fields:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'Chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.aOOlW.bIiDR"))
)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.aOOlW.bIiDR").click()

username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")

username.send_keys("blankspace")
password.send_keys("blankspace")

driver.close()
```

Also consider using the updated methods `find_element()`:

```
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instea
```

Comment: This might be the answer for some people that I don't have a cookie pop up. You were right about needing to have something that waits a couple seconds before searching for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Selenium documentation! [Link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=by#locate-elements-by). By going off the docs you could try the following:

```
username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
username.send_keys("text")
password.send_keys("text")
```

Though I would use XPATH instead as it would be quicker:

```
username = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
password = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
username.send_keys("text")
password.send_keys("text")
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to anyone who cares to know is that Instagram loads in the body of the page after you get to it so you just have to add a delay before you start looking for the elements. Thats to @edd for pointing that out

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
time.sleep(5)
username = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

username.send_keys("blankspace")
password.send_keys("blankspace")
```